# Compile and install printer driver src.rpm for ARM (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: drivers, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compilation

I have an [Epson Stylus NX420](https://epson.com/Support/Printers/All-In-Ones/Epson-Stylus-Series/Epson-Stylus-NX420/s/SPT_C11CA80201?review-filter=Linux) and a Raspberry Pi 3. I am trying to setup [Google Cloud Print Connector](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector) in order to use the Pi as a print server. I am following [this guide](https://github.com/google/cloud-print-connector/wiki/Installing-on-Raspberry-Pi-Raspbian-Jessie), but for Raspbian Stretch.

The first step of the guide is installing the driver and CUPS. I have located some Linux drivers on the Epson site:

- [ESC/P Driver (full feature)](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=16875&DSCCHK=a9c4fba46743be0cb2d94aa2fb14ff87ac792dcf)
- [ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver)](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=75915&DSCCHK=99508ca9a631533bc334fb1f274f96ff1f3ac470)

Neither of them are available for the ARM platform, but both drivers offer `src.rpm` files, which makes me hopeful. I would prefer to use the full-featured one if possible.

I know basically nothing about cross-compiling drivers, so I did some research about my specific situation. What I read led me to try the following (I'll use keywords when referring to filenames to increase [SNR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio)):

- `sudo apt install rpm2cpio` then `rpm2cpio driver.src.rpm | cpio -idmv`, which gives me `filter.tgz`, `nx420.tgz`, and `nx420.spec`.
- `tar -xzf filter.tgz` then `tar -xzf nx420.tgz`, which give me `filter/` and `nx420/`

It's at this point, that I really don't know how to proceed and am mostly just guessing with a bit of information. (Only the `filter/` directory has a `configure` file):

- `cd filter/`
- `chmod +x configure` then `./configure`, which eventually fails with a message about not having a prefix, so I `mkdir prefix eprefix` (because I don't want to install something wrong to `/usr/local` yet) and try again:
- `./configure --prefix=$PWD/prefix --exec-prefix=$PWD/eprefix`, which seems to complete without any obvious errors
- `make` then eventually fails with many errors

Additionally, the `readme` files contain little useful information, and mainly link to the domain http://avasys.jp, which seems to no longer host any relevant information, as far as I can tell. (I can't read Japanese and am using Chrome's built-in translation function.)

Hopefully the above details give you enough precursory info to understand that I'm familiar with bash's built-ins, but have spotty Linux understanding at this point (my background is OS X/macOS). I have never compiled any Linux software other than simple C-family interactive shell programs. If you need more information, please just ask.

How do I compile and install the driver so I can setup this print server?

Comment: Looking at the spec file should give you some idea on how to build it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have updated the question to clarify that I have very little compilation experience. I have never tried to read a spec file before this situation—I didn't even know they existed. There are lots of variables and commands in the spec file that I don't understand, so it isn't of much help to me at this point.

Comment: Is there any rpm based program on raspberry pi3? Src.rpm  should be rebuild as .rpm and then you could install it as a normal rpm.

Comment: Hi @FrontENG. I'm trying to compile it to run natively on my Pi.